# Some questions about Class

Tags: c++

first of all, I have to say this community suggested Primer C++ to me, and so far, it was an amazing experience, and I've learned tons of things, but the class chapter starts a little bit weird.
The code is about two functions called read and print.
I have a problem understanding this code. It will be a huge help if you guys help me thx.

```
//name of the class is Sales_data

istream &read(istream &is, Sales_data &item){
    double price = 0;
    is >> item.bookNo >> item.units_sold >> price;
    item.revenue = price * item.units_sold;
    return is;
}
ostream &print(ostream &os, const Sales_data &item){
    os << item.isbn() << " " << item.units_sold << " "
    << item.revenue << " " << item.avg_price();
    return os;
}
```

my major questions are:

1. why we write istream/ostream as the return type or the parameter
2. why we made a new object as the parameter of the function `Sales_data &item`
3. what is this is/os in this `is >> item.bookNo >> item.units_sold >> price;`
   or this `os << item.isbn() << " " << item.units_sold << " " << item.revenue << " " << item.avg_price();` line

other questions that I have from this chapter so far that I will be so glad if you help me:

1. what is`return *this` generally what is this line or where can I find a clear explanation of 'this'
2. what is the purpose of writing the name of the class as the return type or as the parameter
3. in this code `std::string isbn() const { return bookNo; }` why const is there.
   thank you all

Comment: Can I suggest you now read Stroustrup The C++ Programming Language? The above will then be obvious then.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will take a look

Comment: please one question per question. One problem with many questions in one is that some already have an answer, but we cannot point you to a duplicate question, because it would only fit to 1/6th of your questions

Comment: maybe you find something on the term "operator chaining" most of your questions are related to that. It is actually used in the code: `is >> item.bookNo >> item.units_sold >> price;` this only works because `is >> item.bookNo` returns a reference to `is` so that you can call `>> item.units_sold` on the same object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer your questions:

1. Why write istream/ostream because is the type in both cases: return and parameter. Maybe you need to know that C++ a strongly typed language.
2. Same reason than first point, this isn't a new object, it's the parameter type.
3. In this line you custom the input stream and the ouput stream with the format that you write.